# get ranges inside formula

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would like to know if there is a practical way of extracting the cells that are used in a formula in google scripts?
For an example:
Let's say A1 has a formula as below

`=page1!C2*0,8+page2!B29*0,15+page3!C144*0,05`

I would like `var myCells`record the data of

`page1!C2`
 `page2!B29`
 `page3!C144`

Please let me know how would you make this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are talking about a way to get cell references in general, NO.  If all your formulas look like the one you've shown but with different cell references for all 3 parts then YES.

Comment: How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`range.getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()) to get the formula and then use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) with [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to get the cells:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const f =
  '=page1!C2:C*0,8+page2!B29*0,15+page3!C144*0,056+sheet1!c:c* Sheet56!D10:D-D5:G10';
const matched = f.match(/(\w+!)?[A-Za-z]+\d*(:[A-Za-z]+\d*)?/g);
console.log(JSON.stringify(matched));
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

- `(\w+!)?` - [`?`optional]Matches one or more `w`ord followed by `!` for sheet name(eg: page1!)
- `[A-Za-z]+\d*` - Matches one or more letters `[A-Z]` followed by zero or more digits `\d*` for range string(eg: C2)
- `(:[A-Za-z]+\d*)?` - [optional] another range string match  preceded by a `:`(eg: :C50)

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Here is an sample script that can parse equations as shown into the reference cells.

Note this only works for the specific formula you specified.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheets = spread.getSheets().map( sheet => sheet.getName() );
    // for this test
    sheets = ["page1","page2","page3"];
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let formula = sheet.getRange("A1").getFormula();
    console.log(formula);
    // break into parts
    let parts = formula.split("*");  // but notice this is for specific case of *
    parts.pop() // the last part doesn't contain any cell reference
    console.log(parts);
    let i = 0;
    let results = [];
    parts.forEach( part => {  let j = sheets.findIndex( sheet => part.indexOf(sheet) >= 0 )
                              // remove sheet from range
                              let k = part.split('!')[1];  // this give cell A1 notation
                              results.push(sheets[j]+k)
                           }
                  );
    console.log(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
6:54:44 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:54:46 AM  Info    =page1!C2*0,8+page2!B29*0,15+page3!C144*0,05
6:54:46 AM  Info    [ '=page1!C2', '0,8+page2!B29', '0,15+page3!C144' ]
6:54:46 AM  Info    [ 'page1C2', 'page2B29', 'page3C144' ]
6:54:45 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Range.getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula())
- [String.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [Array.pop()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)